# Flowplayer: Clicking on the player forces is to reload

Tags: flowplayer

I've got this damn annoying bug (or wrong setting) that makes the player reload whenever it's clicked. It's set to play when you click, so when you click it, it reloads. The circle begins....

The reloading only happens in Firefox. In Safari (and I assume Chrome), the video opens in its own window. Not ideal, but it still plays.

Here's the code for the player: *(I can't share the link unfortunately, NDAs etc etc.)*

`flashembed("player", "/flowplayer.commercial-3.0.7.swf", { 
    config: {
        key: '#@xxxxxx',

        clip:  { 
            autoPlay: false, 
            autoBuffering: true,
            url: "http://myvid.com/url.mp4",
            wmode: 'opaque'
        } 
    } 
});`

This site is full of complete geniuses, I hope one of you can help me out!

Comment: Tried it without the autobuffering?

Comment: Also, flowplayer latest version seems to be 3.1.5 (as opposed to your 3.0.7) - try a newer version and see if it still happens?

Comment: With autoBuffering commented out, I still get the same error.
And with 3.1.5 installed, I gen an entirely new error. I have looked through the changelog, it seems nothing been added that should fix this. I don't get the error with other sites of ours using the same player.

Comment: Cos I know Paul personally, I've had a look at the site in question - the issue is limited to Firefox/OSX, as it works fine in Firefox/Win.  Version 3.6 of FF i nboth cases

Answer (score 0):

The fact that this works as expected in Firefox 3.6 for Windows and Firefox 3.5.7 for Linux suggests its a Mac/Firefox issue.

Try comparing the generated output between different versions using [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) and see if you can spot anything

Comment: I've compared the outputs from another site we've used the same player on, with the one in question. Here's what's generated, but reformatted to show differences more: http://pastebin.com/m2bc4a3d8

Answer (score 0):

I just had the exact same issue. I had Flowplayer in a [content slider](http://css-tricks.com/anythingslider-jquery-plugin/) and the slider was cloning the player and the script. I fixed the problem by changing the video link to have a class of "player," instead of a unique ID, then changing the javascript call to Flowplayer to:

```
<script>flowplayer("a.player", "flowplayer-3.1.5.swf");</script>
```

and then moving the script out of the slider, so that the script itself wasn't cloned. I reinserted it just before the closing  tag, but it could go anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue using ajax to swap out the videos based on user action, e.g. clicking a link. I finally resolved it by removing the element and re-adding it prior to calling flowplayer:

```
$("#video #message-video").remove();
$("#video").html( $("<div>").attr("id","message-video") );
flowplayer("message-video", ...
```